# Unicode problems in Python

Tags: python, mysql, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

Huh, ok, so I have this massive problem with encodings and I just do not know how to deal with it. After two days of Google searches I think I just run out of options :)

What I want to do is the following.

1. Place text in a textbox on a website
2. Send the text to the backend (written in Python)
3. Use the text to create:
   a. An image in PIL.
   b. An entry in MySQL.

Now all of this works smoothly when we're talking about regular characters. But when I try to use Korean, Polish, Japanese characters I get very weird looking characters inserted in both the image and the database. In the examples below I'll use a three character string of Polish characters - "ąść".

Here's what I have done after Googling.

Inserted the following in .htaccess:

```
AddCharset UTF-8 .py .css .js .html
```

My python file now starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

All of my MySQL databases are encoded in "utf8_unicode_ci".

Now, here's an example of what I'm trying to do... Whenever I parse "ąść" (three Polish characters) it gets saved in the database and generated on the image as:

```
Ä…Å›Ä‡
```

Now, a few debugging issues. I go directly to Python and assign the following to the variable (value_text1) that usually has its text parsed (so - no text parsing, simply set fixed text to generate the image with and put into the database):

A) If I go with `value_text1 = 'ąść'` I get `…Å›Ä‡` as a result.

B) If I go with `value_text1 = u'ąść'` I get the following error message:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 0-1: ordinal not in range(256)

C) If I go with `value_text1 = u'ąść'.encode('UTF-8')` I get `…Å›Ä‡` as a result.

D) If I go with `value_text1 = u'\u0105\u015B\u0107'.encode('UTF-8')`, where `"\u0105\u015B\u0107"` is the actual unicode for "ąść" I get `…Å›Ä‡` as a result.

Really no clue what I'm doing wrong - server settings, python file settings, wrong command? Will appreciate any thoughts, huge thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you rendering your text in PIL?

Comment: Where do you get that error message?  What is the code that raises that error message?

Comment: maybe your editor isn't saving non-ascii char in utf-8.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I think you always get that error when trying to do `u"somestringwith-ąść"`

Comment: @jazzpi: Not if you have the encodings set properly (unless you try to print it or something).

Comment: Right... So I figured out the MYSQLdb issue simply by adding charset="utf-8" into the connect parameters. PIL is still causing problems though... There's no error message there's simply badly displayed text. I'm wondering if it can be related to the type of font being used - I read it can only be a unicode font. I have however uploaded "Arial Unicode MS.ttf" and this is one is not displaying what I want. That makes me think it's some sort of issue with setting utf-8 into PIL - could that be possible?

Comment: Boom, just solved! Here's what worked for me. Instead of displaying `value_text1` or `value_text1.encode('utf-8')` I would display: `unicode(value_text1,'utf-8')`. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I try it in an interactive shell or from a .py file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
value_text1 = u'ąść'
print value_text1
```

it works perfectly well for me, so I guess it's something with your server configuration.

BTW, make sure to use charset="utf-8" when connecting to the server.

Comment: That might be it... do you know where I could try to search for this configuration? Would that be an Apache thing or .htaccess or something else?

Comment: Assuming you are using the MySQLdb module, just add charset="utf-8" to your MySQLdb.connect() call :)

Comment: Ha nice one! This actually worked, thank you! Now need to figure out the PIL issue and I'm set... I'm definitely a step closer now :)